# How to trim the mp3 song using ff mpeg in PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I need to trim the mp3 song using ff mpeg in PHP .

```
    I tried some code :- 
        $fpath = 'D:\xampp-portable\htdocs\songs\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe';
        $song_path = 'D:/xampp-portable/htdocs/songs/uploads/mp3/test10.mp3';
        $sample_song_path = 'D:/xampp-portable/htdocs/songs/uploads/mp3/sample/test10.mp3';
        exec("$fpath -ss 10 -i '".$song_path."' -t 6 '".$sample_song_path."' 2>&1",$out_put);
        var_dump($out_put);
```

Here I got the error message like below

```
I got output as :- 

Array
(
    [0] => FFmpeg version git-N-28582-g2a0d4d4, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
    [1] =>   built on Mar 23 2011 14:50:54 with gcc 4.5.2
    [2] =>   configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-memalign-hack --arch=i686 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --extra-libs='-lrtmp -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -lz -lx264 -lpthreadGC2' --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --extra-cflags=-I/home/kyle/software/ffmpeg/external-libs/32-bit/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/kyle/software/ffmpeg/external-libs/32-bit/lib --pkg-config=pkg-config
    [3] =>   libavutil    50. 40. 0 / 50. 40. 0
    [4] =>   libavcodec   52.114. 0 / 52.114. 0
    [5] =>   libavformat  52.103. 0 / 52.103. 0
    [6] =>   libavdevice  52.  3. 0 / 52.  3. 0
    [7] =>   libavfilter   1. 76. 0 /  1. 76. 0
    [8] =>   libswscale    0. 12. 0 /  0. 12. 0
    [9] => 'D:/xampp-portable/htdocs/melodic_svn/uploads/mp3/test10.mp3': Invalid data found when processing input
)
```

How can I fix this . Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

In one case you're using slash and in other backslash (`$fpath` and `$song_path`).

First, be sure that the whole command you're going to execute via `exec` is correct. `Echo` it and the paste it into terminal to check if it works. Start debugging to narrow down possible issues.

Comment: Yes, This is command for trim the song ,exec("$fpath -ss 10 -i '".$song_path."' -t 6 '".$sample_song_path."' 2>&1",$out_put);